# navbar and map div takes up the whole screen without scroll

Tags: html, css, materialize

I have a web page with a navbar and map div. Everything is great but there is a scroll bar on the page and you must scroll to see the full map. I would like the full map div to show up on the screen without any scrolling. How do I accomplish this? Thank you

**HTML:**

```
<nav class="default" role="navigation">
  <div class="nav-wrapper">
    <a href="#!" class="brand-logo center">NTN Trails</a>
    <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse show-
      on-large"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
    <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">       
    </ul>
    <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
      <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sign up</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<script>
  $('.button-collapse').sideNav({
  menuWidth: 240, // Default is 240
  edge: 'left', // Choose the horizontal origin
  closeOnClick: true // Closes side-nav on <a> clicks, useful for Angular/Meteor
  }
  );
</script>
<!--put your initial page content here-->
<div id="map"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body, #map {
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 993px){
     nav a.button-collapse {
         display: block;
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove the white-space: `* { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }`. Please note that this will remove the padding and margin of each and every element.

Comment: doesn't seem to change anything.